# No output from main method?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I'm writing a program that should output a table, but no output appears. I don't get any errors - no compile errors or runtime errors from terminal or interactions in my IDE. Here is my full main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  if(args.length < 1){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = input.nextLine();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
    Map<Character,Double> freq = new TreeMap<Character,Double>();
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
      int i = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
      char c = (char)i;
      double d = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());
      freq.put(c,d);
    }
    input.close();
    scan.close();

    HuffmanCode huff = new HuffmanCode(freq);
    for(Map.Entry<Character,String> entry : huff.codeMap.entrySet()){
     System.out.format("%3c%4d%30s", entry.getKey(), (int)entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
  }else{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    Map<Character,Double> freq = new TreeMap<Character,Double>();
    while(scan.hasNext()){
      int i = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
      char c = (char)i;
      double d = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());
      freq.put(c,d);
    }
    HuffmanCode huff = new HuffmanCode(freq);
    for(Map.Entry<Character,String> entry : huff.codeMap.entrySet()){
     System.out.format("%3c%4d%30s", entry.getKey(), (int)entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
  }      
}
```

I'm confused because the program finishes, gives me no errors, but doesn't print anything out. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Edit: Here is my HuffmanCode constructor:

```
HuffmanCode(Map<Character,Double> freqMap){
   this.freqMap = freqMap;
   PriorityQueue<TreeNode> queue = new PriorityQueue<TreeNode>(new NodeComparator());
   for(Map.Entry<Character,Double> entry : freqMap.entrySet()){
     TreeNode temp = new TreeNode(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
     queue.add(temp);
   }
   while(queue.size() > 1){
     TreeNode t1 = queue.remove();
     TreeNode t2 = queue.remove();
     TreeNode node = new TreeNode(t1.freq + t2.freq, t1, t2);
     queue.add(node);
   }
   root = queue.remove();       
   String s = "";
   codeMap = traversal(root,s);       
}
```

Also, I enter a file as an argument,so the first `if` block in the main method isn't involved - just added it for completeness.

Comment: Don't close the `input` `Scanner` in this case (probably won't fix the issue, but it's not a good idea to close the `System.in`)

Comment: I added the constructor, but copying the entire class would lengthy - theres several other methods included

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is without the code for `traversal()`, since the issue is probably that `codeMap` is empty, and `traversal()` appears to be responsible for `codeMap`'s initialization.

Comment: I've tried debugging my code but haven't found anything yet - will continue looking. Ken Slade must be right it has to be a problem with constructing the codeMap. Ill continue debugging until I find the problem!

Comment: Can you attach a sample input? I'm curious about the format of your input.

Comment: `java HuffmanCode simple.frq` ... the frq is just a list of ASCII codes and freqencies. Or did you mean a sample of the data in the file itself?

Comment: Your main throws  IOException. Try enclosing your code with proper try-catch and print the Exception with e.printStackTrace

Comment: I tried that earlier and it didn't print anything either

Comment: You only print something if maps are filled. Maybe add a "start" and "end" output and if you see that - start debugging.

Comment: You keep removing things from the queue until it's empty. So it has no root. I guess that means that codeMap is empty.

Comment: Hmm yes the codeMap seems to return null values. I'll have to find where I went wrong... I would have expected to get some kind of null pointer exception for nodes that point to nodes containing null... I don't think the question is still valid for the null values since the problem is originating from somewhere in the constructor rather than the output.. thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Well, I found the issue after a couple hours of debugging and printing out tables of processing code... The problem was with the traversal method as @KenSlade suggested! Everything was correct, except I was putting elements into a `<Character, String>` tree without converting the ascii code to a `char`, which was making a weird key set of nulls, chars/path codes, and ascii/freq nodes. All I needed was to typecast the `key` parameter to `char` :P